# make hover box fixed

Tags: jquery, css

I want the boxes to be fixed so when you hover over one, this box stays up until you hover over another so the box will stay up when you click in the open space for example.

Code so far:

css

```
.popbox1 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:18px;
border: 0px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 18px;
margin-left:42px;
margin-left:auto
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}

.popbox2 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:18px;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 19px;
margin-left:-210px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}

.popbox3 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:18px;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 19px;
margin-left:-460px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}

.popbox4 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:11.5px;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 18px;
margin-left:-715px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}

.popbox5 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:18px;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 16px;
margin-left:-965px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}


.popbox6 {
display: none;
z-index: -1;
width: 1350px;
height: 275px;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
color: #FF6600;
font-size:18px;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 17px;
margin-left:-1215px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);}

.popbox1 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}

.popbox2 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}


.popbox3 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}


.popbox4 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}


.popbox5 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}


.popbox6 h2 {
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;}
```

javascript

```
<script>
$(function() {
var moveLeft = 0;
var moveDown = 0;
$('a.popper').hover(function(e) {


    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);
}, function() {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).hide();
});

$('a.popper').mousemove(function(e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

    leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
    maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
    windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
    windowRight = 0;
    maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);

    if(maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight)
    {
        leftD = maxLeft;
    }

    topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
    maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
    windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
    maxTop = topD;
    windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
    if(maxBottom > windowBottom)
    {
        topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
    } else if(maxTop < windowTop){
        topD = windowTop + 20;
    }

    $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);

});});
```

Basically I have 6 images, when you hover over 1 a text box appears but as soon as you move the mouse to an empty space, the box disappears. One of the text boxes needs a scroll bar but the box disappears before you can click on the scroll bar. The box should be fixed after you hover onto it so you can use the scroll bar.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Needs more info, or perhaps a JSFiddle -- I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: Much easier to get what you mean if you *do* include the HTML.